# Big O Complexity of Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, big-o, code-complexity

This method seeks to express num as a product of elements in arr.

For e.g method1(37,[1,3,5]) returns [2,0,7]

```
// arr is an array of divisors sorted in asc order, e.g. [1,3,5] 
def method1(num, arr) 
  newArr = Array.new(arr.size, 0)
  count = arr.size - 1

  while num > 0
    div = arr[count]  

    if div <= num
      arr[count] = num/div
      num = num % div
    end 

    count = count - 1
  end 

  return newArr
end
```

Would really appreciate if you could give me some help to derive the complexity of the algorithm. Please also feel free to improve the efficiency of my algorithm

Comment: Where is count initialized?

Comment: A rule of thumb for determining Big-O notation: If you double the size of the input, how much more work does the algorithm need to do: (a) If it does exactly the same input, it's probably O(1). (b) If it does twice the input, it's probably O(n). (c) If it does four times the input, it's probably O(n^2).

Comment: Oh forgot to include the count here. Thanks

Comment: @X.enia: Did you mean to increase the `count` variable instead of decreasing inside while loop?

Comment: Correction - I meant for it to start from the last element of arr

Comment: Looks like N time to me, it's basically looping over the array once right?

Comment: Yes i was thinking the worst case is to loop through the entire arr. But I was wondering if there would be any other worse situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
def method1(num, arr)

    newArr = Array.new(arr.size, 0)
    count = arr.size()-1

    while num>0
        div = arr[count]

        if div <= num
            arr[count] = num / div
            num = num % div
        end

        count = count + 1
    end
    return arr
end


ar = Array.new(25000000) { rand(1...10000) }

t1 = Time.now
method1(37, ar)
t2 = Time.now

tdelta = t2 - t1

print tdelta.to_f
```

Output:

```
0.102611062
```

Now double the array size:

```
ar = Array.new(50000000) { rand(1...10) }
```

Output:

```
0.325793964
```

And double again:

```
ar = Array.new(100000000) { rand(1...10) }
```

Output:

```
0.973402568
```

So an `n` doubles, the duration roughly triples. Since O(3n) == O(n), the
whole algorithm runs in O(n) time, where n represents the size of the input
array.

Comment: I see, that's very useful! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `O(3n)` should be `O(1.5n)`, but it's `O(n)` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refactored version of your code :

```
def find_linear_combination(num, divisors)
  results = divisors.map do |divisor|
    q, num = num.divmod(divisor)
    q
  end
  results if num == 0
end

puts find_linear_combination(37, [5, 3, 1]) == [7, 0, 2]
puts find_linear_combination(37, [1, 3, 5]) == [37, 0, 0]
puts find_linear_combination(37, [5]).nil?
```

With `n` being the size of `divisors`, this algorithm clearly appears to be `O(n)`. There's only one loop (`map`) and there's only one integer division inside the loop.

Note that the divisors should be written in descending order. If no linear combination is found, the method returns nil.

If you want to sort `divisors`, the algorithm would be `O(n*log n)`. It could also be a good idea to append `1` if necessary (`O(1)`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Divisors isn't a problem as it can assumed as being sorted in ascending order already